# Storage required on each member for a partitioned persistent region

Tags: size, storage, persistent, partition, gemfire

In case of a persistent partitioned region, what data is stored in the associated disk-store on ANY ONE MEMBER. Is it all the data for the region including those held on other members, or is it just the primary data THE MEMBER is hosting, or is it the primary and any redundant data THE MEMBER is hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data in the disk store is just the primary and redundant data that the member is hosting, not all of the data for the region.